# Exclude URL from yoast sitemap

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have several URLs in the sitemap that are generated by Yoast.

I am not able to find the page as it is deleted a long time ago, redirection exists to another page which works fine.

I have found a code snippet that works but only for pages or post ID. As I don't know Page ID, is it possible to remove it by slug?

A function that works for page ID.

```
function exclude_posts_from_xml_sitemaps() {
    return [ 1, 2, 3 ];
}
```

```php
add_filter( 'wpseo_exclude_from_sitemap_by_post_ids', 'exclude_posts_from_xml_sitemaps' );
```

I need to delete URL that looks like

```
https://website/example2
https://website/example3
https://website/example4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the pages' slugs, you can retrieve their IDs using the [get_page_by_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) function.

Your code can look like this:

```php
function exclude_posts_from_xml_sitemaps() {
  $slugs = array('example1', 'example2', 'example3');
  $ids = array();

  foreach ( $slugs as $slug ) {
    $page = get_page_by_path( $slug );

    if ( $page !== null ) {
        $ids[] = $page->ID;
    }
  }

  return $ids;
}
```